# Tons of controller errors in MVC called by Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm getting sporadic error messages from our web server that has an MVC application. The messages are:

> The controller for path '/scan' was not found or does not implement
>   IController.
>
> The controller for path '/scan.com' was not found or does not
>   implement IController.
>
> The controller for path '/scan.exe' was not found or does not
>   implement IController.
>
> The controller for path '/scan.vbs' was not found or does not
>   implement IController.
>
> The controller for path '/scan.js' was not found or does not implement
>   IController.
>
> The controller for path '/scan.pif' was not found or does not
>   implement IController.
>
> The controller for path '/scan.scr' was not found or does not
>   implement IController

All of these messages appeared within the same minute.

When I look at the server variables, I see that these requests are coming from the HTTP_USER_AGENT: Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.3.9600

Can someone explain this to me? Or how to fix it? We really don't believe this is our application causing this. We're thinking it's a virus on the server. These file names have nothing to do with our application.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has this type of problem, my solution was to at least add a routes.IgnoreRoute to the application since all these calls started with the word scan.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{scan}/{*pathInfo}", new { scan = @"scan*.*"});
```